# Make could not see commands (recipes) except gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, cygwin

My system is windows 8.1. I'm working on cygwin 32 bit version (first i set up 64 bit version and could not uninstall completely , later set up 32 bit version).I simply want to use 'make' utility. All my makefiles' extensions are 'makefile'.
When i try this below (to see them work , I only use simple makefiles)

```
make kernel.o (in shell)

kernel.o : kernel.c
<tab>gcc - ffreestanding -c $< -o $@
```

it works , and compiles.
But these ones below do not work. And for testing purposes and keeping things simple, each source and corresponding makefiles are in own directory. And all make commands've been made in the current directory where source and corresponding makefiles are located.
All executables (nasm ,ld ,objcopy ,cat) that cygwin needs to run the recipes are in the same directory (that is c:\cygwin\bin\)

If i command the recipes from shell, they work.
I also changed source files to see what would happen.

I also thought that maybe the problem is from cygwin itself , and i set up linux ubuntu desktop version to my machine. But they are (recipes below) not working too.(and also If i command the recipes from shell, they work.)

```
make kernel_entry.o (in shell)
make: *** No rule to make target 'kernel_entry.o'.
Rule:
kernel_entry.o : kernel_entry.asm
<tab>nasm $< -o $@ -f coff     (coff for windows)

//--------------------------------

make os-image.bin (in shell)
make: *** No rule to make target 'os-image.bin'.
Rule:
os-image.bin: boot.bin kernel.bin 
<tab>cat $< > $@

//--------------------------------

make boot.bin 
make: *** No rule to make target 'boot.bin'.
Rule :
boot.bin : boot.asm
<tab> nasm $< -f bin  -o $@

*recipes with ld and objcopy also does not work.*
```

Thank you in advance...

These are my files and directory appearance :

```
C:\cygwin\bin   --> where gcc.stays
C:\cygwin\bin   --> where make.exe stays 
C:\cygwin\bin   --> where objcopy stays
C:\cygwin\bin   --> where nasm.exe stays
C:\cygwin\bin   --> where ld stays

C:\cygwin\home\me\OS\boot    --> where boot.makefile stays and also boot.asm source code
C:\cygwin\home\me\OS\kernel  --> where kern.makefile stays ( working sample ) and also kernel.c source code
```

And this is cygwin shell appearance:

```
me@Me ~/os/kernel
$ dir
kern.makefile  kernel.c  kernel_entry.asm
```

**in my kern.makefile the existing rule is as follows

```
kernel_entry.o : kernel_entry.asm
    nasm $< -o $@ -f coff
```

and boot directory

```
me@Me ~/os/boot
$ dir
boot.asm       disk_load.asm  print_hex.asm     print_string_pm.asm
boot.makefile  gdt.asm        print_string.asm  switch_to_pm.asm
```

**in my boot.makefile the existing rule is as follows

```
boot.bin : boot.asm
    nasm $< -f bin  -o $@
```

Comment: Seeing the actual directory layout, the actual Makefile, and the actual command (including working directory) would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @DevSolar . I edit  (add directory appearance) to my question. I coludn't see any problem though. If you could see , please warn.

Comment: And i want to add that i've compiled these source codes directly from  windows and cygwin shells(nasm,gcc,ld,objcopy)  without make utility and write it to a flash disk , and boot a machine and enter protected mode without any problem.

Comment: Well, if you had *seen* the problem with the directory layouts, you wouldn't have had to come here to ask about it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make does not see your makefiles.**

From the GNU make manual:

> If no `-f` option is present, `make` will look for the makefiles `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order.

From what I see, your makefiles (`kern.makefile`, `boot.makefile`) are simply not found by your call to `make` (which does not have a `-f` option). This makes `make` rely on its internal rules, which do not include any `%.o: %.asm` dependency or somesuch (for `make`, assembly ends in `.s`, assembly with preprocessing to be done in `.S`).

This can become *bloody* confusing when your `*.c` and `*.S` files *are* compiled into `*.o` files, because `make` *does* have internal rules for those -- which, of course, stubbornly refuse to take any compiler options into account that you might have defined in that makefile of yours that `make` doesn't actually read. ;-)

So either call

```
make -f kern.makefile kernel.o
```

or (and this is my recommendation), **rename `<whatever>.makefile` to `Makefile`** (which is the canonical way of naming those).

Comment: Generally speaking, I've [always advocated](http://wiki.osdev.org/Required_Knowledge) *against* "learning the ropes" of any toolchain while working on an OS. You *should* learn these things working on userspace programs, because kernel space definitely is a very hostile and unforgiving environment.

Comment: I read that sentence before, and actually got wrong . I understood this part "GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile,in that order." as these must be file extensions , not the files themselves. Thank you @DevDolar.

Comment: In fact , i haven't been much into os spesific details before (whether current oses or from scratch). I have developed a yacc-like parser generator , and now working on a php (a lite version ) alternative server side script language. I want to make things simplier , may be simpliest.

Comment: I actually find a note about os that seems very simple , and decide to try as a hobbiest . [link](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf)

Comment: @Tanzer: It is "simple" (yet still a monumental amount of work) for an experienced programmer. For a beginner, it's just a couple of additional complications on top of learning language, toolchain, and environment. I've been active on [osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org) for years (and cannot recommend that Wiki and Forum enough), but the overall sentiment over there *is*, first learn to program, *then* start toying with your hobby OS. (As indicated by the wiki page I linked to.)